# Disk looks fine, but mount fails (bad option, bad superblock)

Tags: lvm, ext4

I've got a disk that's a bit of a mess right now, but I feel like I've got it into a state where it's working. Here's the original question about how the block size was wrong:
https://superuser.com/questions/1597651/recovering-a-logical-volume-whos-disk-has-been-removed-and-plugged-back-in?noredirect=1#comment2434932_1597651

I've fixed that with losetup, and have the new loop device showing a valid logical volume (lvdisplay once again shows the volume group), and dumpe2fs shows that nothing is wrong as far as I can tell:

```
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /mnt/newDisk
Filesystem UUID:          7a0d44bf-87cd-42ae-9999-44c69d66fa16
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              183144448
Block count:              1465129984
Reserved block count:     73256499
Free blocks:              1453293951
Free inodes:              183144437
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         4096
Inode blocks per group:   256
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Oct 20 13:39:23 2020
Last mount time:          Tue Oct 20 13:40:23 2020
Last write time:          Tue Oct 20 13:40:23 2020
Mount count:              1
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Oct 20 13:39:23 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          1039 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      c8d38b88-946f-475e-89cc-41e4b87c765c
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x22c5114b
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3
Journal size:             1024M
Journal length:           262144
Journal sequence:         0x00006538
Journal start:            209904
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x56fe4f79
```

I've tried mounting an offset superblock with `mount -o sb=32768 /dev/tmpVG/temporary /mnt` but I still get the "bad option, wrong fs type" error.

Am I missing something here? I feel like I'm mounting the wrong thing, but I don't know what I'm supposed to be mounting. How do I check if the superblock is actually good vs guessing?

edits:
file -s shows something interesting

```
/dev/dm-2: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=7a0d44bf-87cd- 
42ae-9999-44c69d66fa16 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) 
(large files) (huge files)
```

fsck seems to only print the version information, the wrong executable, and then exit. adding verbosity doesn't help:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/mapper/tmpVG-temporary] fsck.ext2 /dev/mapper/tmpVG-temporary
```

"needs journal recovery" I think is a clue, I guess I'll look into that next

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file -s /dev/tmpVG/temporary` to find out if you are looking at an ext4 file system at all. The option *sb* is only valid, if you mount an actual ext2, ext3 or ext4 filesystem.

Alternatively you can try to use fsck, use the parameter *-N* to *Don't execute, just show what would be done.* `fsck -N /dev/tmpVG/temporary`

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question with some more information